# Find Accuracy of an agglomeration method?

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

I have plotted a dendrogram using maximum agglomeration method.

```
hc <- hclust(distance_matrix, method = "complete")
plot(hc, hang = 0, labels=ilpd_df$Class)
```

Q1) How can I find the accuracy of this agglomeration method?

Q2) How should one comment on the sensitivity of test data to the agglomeration method?

Thank you =)

Comment: I don't think that either 'accuracy' or 'sensitivity' are meaningful words in this context. However if you want to measure the appropriateness of a hierarchical clustering then the simplest method maybe the `cophenetic` function. See `help(cophenetic)`

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: @MrFlick please encourage *migration*, not duplication, of questions. If you have enough reputation, you can also flag as off-topic, belongs to, CV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cluster analysis is explorative, not predictive.

Accuracy makes sense when predicting, but not so much when exploring data. You won't be able to just apply this clustering method to a new data point!

The closest to accuracy is probably the Rand index if you actually have labeled data. It's the accuracy of predicting for a pair of points if they have the same label, or not.